# accessing mail and its content using php

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have been working onseting upa application where one can login and set up his mail so that hecan send mail using that website application.

I am able to get the mail conetnt using imap but the mail format that i am getting is as below

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHQAAAApCAYAAADkig0OAAAYeElEQVRYw+1ZaZhU5ZV+v+/eulXV
>   1RsNdEPTAi2IuKAiKsYF0YgQRQ2aEI1OjJpoVFwSjcZlBqPGjI5LxnHXREWig0aNihuikUU0iKKs
>   Nk0v9FK91F53v/db5ge3SNl2Q+tgMhP9nqeeB6q7v+W857znnPcQfIl19t1+xHXMCoeRUEgaPESl
>   vuiGOhOAxDfrM+s7755UGg6XHi9UOo9JMtzlXGb9PFrijdzstu/3bk4slN2eD0DsjvPIYH7p3N8Z
>   o0xfm57OY7ZhYJLryhG+j1IpZVihkOGwzEYjvCMaFS1h6nwoPHNlb9OK1asX/ehrDfL0v0wLJ43s
>   aemezAkirOxfVjf0EBrS0N3aCWt15hn/Hv1qAFkABgD+lQN6wX3O/kkrdHV7nPwg2eNprmm0EZZY
>   LpzuBgW6zjlRoVRUS6XmMEGHTA1Fw9GKISFUVgGaypqIb7yY79ly/4cLp7cGHvh1BFcFEKm5cfR3
>   rYP8J6VK4X6Sh3xXXsFeNRYD6AFg7a4IVfv78uKHZDjn8X/bHFeuamt2NT/fvZQlX3k8+eHVHwtm
>   egB8ACwAiABQysZ+vxajzj6xJ7P/eemeIbWV1do4RSn/heUeeO4eJ2/5vZ9++67ud3/Wu7s88f/R
>   EgDc8NhS4mo6OAeISkE0+AAcAN7uArNfQM+526xN2fK/G1vp0fGmnEVyS27oWj739eBwI/AmPwCm
>   EHFUb302pbc+u6Vi3FnP01GX39pj1s1SQgp82x1CJH6i2j0vAMgBsL9mkSoACFJCPSkBKSUkAQiF
>   LPxsdx5GP0uxskYX0VcbW3F0fEvWFF2PXtG1fO4bAc93A0gCyAeguoF3eUVgZ3JNf9ycWH7Y2Rqa
>   nnAzCRCvs5133X5J8qP5CQDK1zWfCikhZeDKcodH73bH3hGhF/yXiCQs8UxnLz2ws1GHor98W/ea
>   q1YHIGYC0OQgvNEB4CtaNKNQcyvr/s3lRtvibUF0ul9fQAEp5A5gyVfEUTsitNcUtybzdFrXNheK
>   17QivuKcVwGkvwCYO9Z+57QpiiLeZt23n2y0Lf40SPzZgKq/llUvlwUwtwP6VRlBBYDTbnEOTJv0
>   knRCwsmZAsnnnwSgByC4XxSEjU+M9gC8DiASfOUUFVFfy8WD6BQSgJS7OXP2ATRtKVcaLrR8yoMq
>   E1t61t/xcZArnf9F0mZBrpVfZI/c/EsmEsM9gpv+GAFIFg23Z2z3o4kPPrHuy7Q+csOPhnJfP0k4
>   +uFEurVCApJGOx2PbOhKOq/tc/qy9i/bUs29ywtJSYiERLZ7K2FMwvMAQxfImRWaY4ZCsvfubO9H
>   twtOXAixnXalkJCDkADsO3+piLx9rLS8o4QnhjNV1V0uNjdlUkuPeuK5rv7sqp44369J6ORU2wI8
>   24PCuz4RzDaDapT9L5xFDrZFce6br8qe9Hlo7b7IWblplGXYCcaFDHOlPhyOlNQOrUDv93/wUQbu
>   I7Nef/OxFt3cpbJirr1oZET2XMuT685y85mcofsNjAk3rPKxFeXqqRVlpSirLs3m35z83OrN1q3H
>   X9awbVfAzv13fQ/dCv0wa2CG4BjT2SUrS2LCjUTAtcp6+IYkloOSvMuI5zqNmpr8z1xy/YsAHCb5
>   droVQXG0M3vccwMRqdzP5EfNP/d60uWW63ZLT1TGiDambEgF9o9FEy2nnbLg7s0bf3PP5qZcsS3U
>   vMmnO45a7lgCknFId9umov7oK6fI/J3X7Utauh9la7d8q0nPPbwwnXzqP7a2tQOQM6oqKy8eXnPK
>   5ETuqvKqIQcPj0UfePvAb81d7HT95NI1G9sGcjh//cUnKG7TH/zk1mFrN9q/mnNLz6tdGc6Ch5NH
>   Ly4/5OSDzd8Mq83vVRaNnX/M3nzmmofqzj/kwo53+svz593LqOnK67e04MpMUv+Q6a0vg5muDNXO
>   IFr1nIqhIURLKPSs06V3rb+Pu7rjJZasyGy6uzmo7AlYGFI4kIIAggxoWfuBG4ehpWeh/LhxZoOe
>   vm3+tvb/fjmeyAMg908cf8SsvH7z0KphY4ao6pVXlddOtcY5cx9t6kwUbKFUHXjDRa5PD/NsAea4
>   ENnlT1tdSxt2pxw1IJi/u25SOJ5e4q3dsu9bucRV0z/4ZMGqdC4ZnG022056USr14bihkXU1aTY7
>   AhLSGKkf7dFpfpl8bU1GN/pGqr9h3rEqa3nJ722senqJef7sX3ctMxxpBinEAGC+9IHbElLVpftV
>   uLNjUVauhFBeHbFP2mdc9J3nVji9xXtecC/Xsq58Yus2clm6s+33254ddUO+8aGN+abHNulb7nmt
>   bNTR3dnc0G9bpkJsi8YIS3R2v33sw07i/Z6i9o6pp1bt56vu96QAZMoH4ngFW7xPi1Ui+8H5laQj
>   /apc13TMe9meG498/+M/btGtfFDP6K8k04171JT+dW8Tp6lMhmXSHl0XDpU9nuxdVqhRqGWJeuYD
>   nAsQAkB6bvBD8VWCad13fZXWnf+TbOqs3ZhMvfTdNRveDB6XCirrfPDJXLq1ZfGmqPPbTE8WwnYQ
>   zcvJP5VV9wMoK+5tzbUX1Spe21My31GyeVP+Tz++u/vjwBipoG0yAJgA8r993tzU0KNele8wpXRs
>   qGBVs/dzHpx1aGh4cTuXssRt3Wnlh6m43tb56tRHAttkgz2TnUtPfDCqdv7Bs10QgDJ137NGz3zt
>   xOAco8B0bAfdyu09TH+tTWfqTrqte2pnT2LjzNXr/hykvXRwXh5A7qoNW1clKHulK55Fc94C7+YX
>   XFAzfBKAMABCfY+MZH6B1wlANeXvQbUynr6WJjITjLYE3tRzbwaXzwSgFqtQAoCzwEjck6asyc7b
>   kJKjPEe/80D96NkAogVNOiLitxKWGmEnU1i+3l8Z7Jnrp7iTAPxjb8n/WXfoe17OASRHhLMD/m0O
>   OTvYk554ozspkafz0gkBbnU3MCfJA8PqQeS5AExYq29VKc+CAESh8Ok+5yvhytKgLZTb25a/FUT9
>   FoM3zztQ7c39mPVksNVzPmBC+sHdrSKmlB2nHDeSmGKfrYaLra5rrhfGK52OGwKgASCU+SLMmdie
>   sEGgloyoGuwU5suu5L/+tI52Z38iUlnkdMf50DC2BR49UFUtX+zJ6FaJeNrxOATj4AKot8JnASgF
>   oNofnz6Ger3fh6fDztns006/K9hzoLZLAvBsoi7wHQEwDiEkRkfYaUHkq4kcnaMbUC1DgEjbDqLN
>   7XNH0bHswjZNc97mTABCgvmhsWWjT64vRA0ACCECdWEAQaA7cyZ0izLDRoKKrsAWO85KXXjWEamZ
>   s57yN+TWxfNOeFPYuP0JdJ95eb79+ldy+eYC5aoUftLzle10CwoaqZ+wI5F/RUtL5E5AwqzkWQO2
>   L7xu5uuBsXaWs4UZ5S/yvLyWM6kISEQc5ZCp0eiIv9p2XmGJY8H0Euk78F3OdIsVNOedpQ6ZZeSt
>   kZI4gokIBKAxse+/HK2MeXIFz6WyZGqISnAGCBIb/jfh7vNtZijkv+UwnAbJITiPqNGa4QBCgR2l
>   EHKn6hBJ5Q+VJoNwfEhJBAD20DFTSn4weuwZsjN/kbWyce9uy1z1nm9ccl2uY3Wecx7YzCrK1aBS
>   +l2C8+2USylkaMQ+wUW+Mt1VJHNTRNYAsz1AQqlUFGUwObvZcxuEIuNCbEdeMFROIOHRADTpZfYG
>   swHmQYEM1QzVIjsBYMd66A1nm1BI43Y6BISLkr1rZB0AzbVliWUGIyW1YrRWWqf11b93RFiIbiOE
>   QHIOcMd181uNgX63743Ez88Iy3S+Xhg2BJcYxmntksMOOmW2rS3Krmm9bmNn/K/3GvE5U1o2zpvX
>   sW15nvMcgASA3iBN2YU0pSrEXS9Y+AeEEBBKIHjV5Mq9zqzNNj6d/DJgHXN1XlUUIBSSIESC+RKm
>   IdAd5ySZTIX1d/YxQ4nUnsJUIZhESJDofiUlw19HZpeMcEVjm7G2bv9PpSf34ELAFZISV4kBUKWV
>   qdqOiISiSGXCSKU6MOhO9/3DUo/dfXakEVJO4j7gWYSEhSgBoEjufup7ynQlpECQspHVh9w4peOd
>   n3QWoq54n5AWcgAJ7jmgPN1itL+eGGxh2RVPaSV5N0wEgeQSZZyMfiGVXriUy7cf7ujKZhlTi3Ty
>   AhX3q7ypiky+DRGF5ASEUghopWV7/nR2tvHphsEOXvf7cUqLlcjZPlOvSib4GC0MUl4m3XAEjhAS
>   tslh6Z6gYTYfwMs2YwY1JYhCoUrQceHo2EHSvKQEPVICnpCwJBe66rnwQByLGKp0oWgUqgaMHk4K
>   e9JdULmkGlJEAsyV8CzweAY6AEJF98vcG/ozAQ2gClWrZpwD4M0gN/ufSSNaZJTwfXDXBHWWPSm5
>   Y32ulx+AK5Z0J6wZfihR5qGWSIJyTuvvamqLB1HoFTqyohQyIOtQK/7GJwrMTdz3IKUAKAVT9/1h SfWUqoB6d7r2Py+h2aZ/enur9b3O5q7O7ubmt+JNjYu3Neu5VEJOzGbkxM42NtE1O1vzSw/5EEAk
>   IbDRdgQ4E1AJwViqTRoszSsErpQStpDIw8+sE3YvAOlYYouj+xA+QygM1A+XhwR70l3qnyHiQ0q4
>   uoRuysTrmxAHIHreOO5tTUm/6pkGpO/BETXHjp+z8qxAo96x75m3mdT3Qhf6lgmNbH4sufaaJUE1
>   /DdAZR/KLfr/ucs+5paQW12bA1Ki0qN73rnv+KkBeIX2x+lT/ff/lvh719hjZp/4iGeG7iaEgmoh
>   MBYbM+ywB+e1LT70xkEUFn7zsyOeAfByUHGGAdBh0977hanXH0iIgJ01QFlTs+SuCkAkJVtJPApJ
>   AJUQ1HnqUTURraTH8XYJqAolyoREljH0UndtE2NZACyeEsv2INylRIbVMEF1OZsyd1rJiGeWW6ld
>   je0UFaXckDCTEl0WVm/ugQ7A9402j6UWXaCVnLLA1cuOo1qUGNHJtx90Xsuo6ljr78vKK+JlQ+sP
>   6EzRa5IJdoQmPrwpsWrO80V9oz/AuBuQnyWjrCqWqTY/vYwQRCnB8aTspwCWBGD6X2R8Jr3kKwtU
>   YrVw14b0GZSQhEf2unDMjIXHBN44IBVu+MPwgr95Qd+UANBNQ+XMszlckwHSh2QeL9DGgx3xFRlV
>   rMlbHEIC5R4d/euxo48tLvMHvDBR6nXOkRIM62C8VJApD76kq1G36OtGwgf3OaIRUXHFyeE5faNp
>   ACNMNFMSRhrijW14IUg1HgDR9d513akPTp0b4htuhtOxydcTViIz9AojPPUdv3Ti5ng++pfGrXyW
>   4n5wY2LVnEWBEJAKChU5UFT2XW3SfiknhZG3OUAJRpj0yD8fPOmMXdm/33lo1/u/ykZCjZdL32bM
>   MSF8AUWlYVSc8OD4mY8fVmhadzHY9oJHWABs0AinFCB0+7iIEFKYusg/dqS9bSXuTSmXIeswEAEc
>   5cUuiSg0tjOa33TskROEISd3Mh8dirH0j7axqsiDxfpuer2eFLl83Ae4xIF1/rkXzI7VBffvd3lv
>   jposde/gVCuwxcST//kuPu4TFdzLN+V6Vp50R3LFwTPdpitnOo3zZ8eb25dsayPVHe0CVi7f27N8
>   zuKAHtP91h4Sf9Nw+5k/fW/N5o6eqP9o0vSRdzhAKA41ojc9O2Xyd74IqAXPFW1vzHojqrXdxB0T
>   vqnDdxgkIjVyyOxn9jv9tZmDAPWzGysEhGK71CXl9vxc9LwzPm18PR5z7otbPlIeR8wgByzde78b
>   AJQMFFGhbj6/y3Ai7cT69AmWvq1IzmMA5Kl35Bo6PfXKXDuX6XYG6ns1t5xJbx9RRcv6y89yRb2i
>   mvk7klu42pnEO+e/ggcDuuyrY7Pgu4TR9ty61Ia7VzE/Eu1uZ8imBSS08qGTflG/U3FEVTlUClAC
>   xCigkb6/I5Y5mX9PKP6GDt1D2nJBPJQeaZc+tmraMZfOGbtHWX92adj/oJq1e02cUKjoix8p9JYn
>   Pqjc82TqOeGjOWMQgoIoWkyJ1Z1Wf+h5scoR49cltr7uDEYaHLLPZdMdE0dz14DwTVDR9b6XePn9
>   4NEcgPyTnnlnWklsuOdhihDAcEs55F/qaipKy8Nr3s/mdlBW84xvV81TR/yut03/8Ubk318geq9Z
>   z/x2AMlgv4Jx5GPv+ptmHhjqDGX4UcyUkfIoGzdvTvjwU6eXN/z+NbursKe3dPTBJJ16Kr3ZOLah
>   Gc/8aDFu7jG367NFc9z+xoEeALfqgF/u77raNEoBqqpquGrKkdV7Td+QbniquT9A6WlVM6Bbs5Bk
>   ABMgtVFaOWmPhpLT66T97RjwVsZdqZv2uDL1L5pHpxuuqGY+R8jjoWEmZpwwpPq7F06YUHvR+PHV
>   80aNrb90xB7HXBQefrmVsad/An3Fi3ldx+cy83aUo8MOW3CmL/e+ScjYSBougRaLIVoWQnk531YR
>   zS8gLPXcyocP2zBQCT31Z617tm7lD+hJ8wT4OQjuQyUN9xibL7oTQE9RkUIBxOZX1syt88KX1yAy
>   qYaGUFampUSFtoRGQj3UEWO8jDstoetsLck+/Gsr+SddCiugNr2fgoEAiNwwQzloWrW8rLYCs6qq
>   UVk+goKWhZuIpsWp71V7Obcu1cU+Xt6AR3+0CKuLhPBBTZnGzFhY7SjHrWK+Mk4Ja4iWqghpwgvx
>   jls2P73fHZ+RCB+cWIO2nlfRbtfDkQQgBBVKiA6NGBBYJ9zIDbinc23wFvWk0rJRx5Pymyo87Ywy
>   ooQqFRXlVEFEUQFC4HMBm/kyrVkLH/FTty42jcKEyiMD0HCkYq8LJtCKky7lcthsIUurSSgKNRJF
>   OKahJEZFSZSt11SxlRIRpwoM5qNECDnSMsn4dMo/wM5lBVhvIxGprfDb17P88uVO16sbgoLB6+tE
>   pZRWnhOtPG4U0abU0dD+lUIdrlDoFvimdrhrFzrZVR95boHS8v2I+H1BDQOInX0wGX/EKEyuHUbG
>   DB+CISFNWHkLHWvasOFXf0ZTYHQ7cA5nIDDn/jY/OWeQ47J5HJXL8JG5tB3zTHMU9/kQkBBCsTKU
>   VIRBiIQq2+7Y+uykG4N9BW4eVYI1uRps8cpgyzJIKJCQ0CCRlyn0slSR4C+DaU/svFjl4aMQOqFU
>   qAdoXC1TIKWgIpOn/kdrYa18wTKbCtOjglo0UE4kQc6MRUecUBcZceJ0SUYfJVC+lyQlw0Cj5ZKE
>   ooQqlCrSgxQ5SJaS0o0TmdlMvPaNXmrpFqt9UW9RBWwFl7b7MRoJiqFIMOkIFxVHPPj4RUqJNwjB
>   gwTOEg721Yr2lH32HFB5Ofsu48zejHJZays/XM9YvcJLL5NufC287rhvtmYks0uU8unn+6g7Xi0p
>   R6Q0AsYkwnLj1e2vHX1/UbWrBvdQ+6FyP3hT8R2UglMGNtGK6gDWpwh1CzYlgzCIVmToiBKpLlFi
>   EyqAijDgcck6TWa0WJLbhX61AEDhUD/4Nyu6sNzJmUrwaKVIYhPB3/IvMaclRW8pVqNE0X6fu8+5
>   dxkh3ScPxJPK+S0NNnh+4z25Ty563M2sN4reVWAIdfgRL//SkxOuoJEyEEUDlVbSa75iWr7l+eY+
>   jDSgYrUTDNQ+d5dFNv7M/dVdHMADL3ADjla506twp1fpo5MWjC76gMoHI5D3ObMA/G4bvfZxikGt
>   hI7fZUzl/NZPbYjsstt7V3z3qcKQuSiiC8YkiVUnz685+vk21zvgNoQQ8jmGhUfMPg4tz3cNQpzZ
>   FQZ8sH+gDnZAEnz8Is9BH5Fa4p9kzbgmfUhPml6cTXO4+d7m9KoznguATO5E3+Y9K057eMRx7+9t +7UXQjB4Trg2YDfjSwL6hRfdDV4v/5nABIB4L07MpgXMHANFpi0Q2nO7GFYIADal2ccJIUIyBipz
>   ThA09O91dxXfrM+tdJLVSqgQXIKolcMCeh0MbQqtdEzezhBAOD7LLtuwq+nI/5UI/adeGslv80wH
>   gksIZdg+tcc8+q1BjvdQUlZ2MHM9qpD4W3rroubP9KPfAPqPWUS0vACWN7hjQkqikMqTb9n7pIWH
>   70r+PHJex7h0L7mN8GyH333vnUVjr78boOQb+PqfqNV+++0LTWPEvUSNECVaitIKxRpakXogTHOL
>   cm1LNmxacv0OCXTWtcmafJ6f0tLE/sPKJJPIPnJZruHepqCIyu3mqv0bQL+kXcLDpi78HhNjrxWo
>   2BehGLSSKKKlKmIl6FJUkYSU3HdRZpl8pKlbFvy2hfbWf13gJFbpAZC5IPfKbwD9xy8KIKxEqqvK
>   9/r5dKnWT5OkarygsSoJLUIo4QQ8S2E0wW9Z5XQu+MDpXZ4LRAQ9kOTY37sD+AbQXdunWJKM9JHg
>   ivtzL8iXdpGK9A+58DdrcHbqK0mSPqB+WWlyt67/AUiUByHuYYLHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

So how can i get in as format as in i get in m gmail. Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Yours faithfully,
Santosh Upadhayay
Mo :- +91 9004980633

Comment: You need to use base64_decode function to decode it. It look like broken png.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just use php imap? You need to do many things in order to read the mails. There is an open source repository you can use: https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap